# Javascript regex match formatting to parse data

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match data within a string in order to parse the data. The format for the data is follows

A*(anything)B*(anything)ABC*(anything)

The keys will always be A, B, ABC or DCE.

I have it working for the keys with the length of one character.

```
$(function() {

var s = "A*(anything)B*(anything)ABC*(anything)DCE*(anything)";

s.match(/(A|B|ABC|DCE)\*[^*]+(?!\*)/g).forEach(match => {
    var [k, v] = match.split('*');

    console.log(k + "->" + v);
});

});
```

However, this is the output (doesn't work with 1+ length keys

```
A->(anything)
B->(anything)AB
DCE->(anything)
```

The value is not always (anything) - it is dynamic.

I think the issue is with **(?!*)/g**

Comment: Are the desired values always in parentheses like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get your logic working using a formal regex matcher.  The problem with your regex pattern is that you are using a negative lookahead to stop the match.  Instead, use a *positive* lookahead which asserts that we have reached the next `(A|B|ABC|DCE)*` or the end of the string.

```
var s = "A*(anything)B*(anything)ABC*(anything)DCE*(anything)";
var regexp = /(A|B|ABC|DCE)\*(.*?)(?=(?:A|B|ABC|DCE)\*|$)/g;
var match = regexp.exec(s);
while (match != null) {
    print(match[0].split("\*")[0] + "->"+ match[0].split("\*")[1]);
    match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

### Demo

Comment: Great, this works like a charm. Is there a way to store "A|B|ABC|DCE" in a variable and then implement it into the regex from the variable?

Comment: @AhmedEnzea Yes, you may use a `RegExp` object constructor, [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).  Just pass any string you wish to the constructor.

Comment: You are right about the placeholder! Deleted my answer and upvoted yours.

Comment: @Thefourthbird It's sometimes hard here to even figure out what is being asked.  I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

why not using `[^\)]` instead of `[^*]`

```js
var s = "A*(anything)B*(anything)ABC*(anything)DCE*(anything)";

// s.match(/[ABCDE]+\*[^\)]+\)/g).forEach(match =>
// or
s.match(/(A|B|ABC|DCE)\*[^\)]+\)/g).forEach(match => {
    var [k, v] = match.split('*');

    console.log(k + "->" + v);
});
```

Comment: This happens to work for the exact example input given, but it would fail if, for example, the content were `this (and) that`, or anything else which doesn't always terminate in closing parenthesis.

Comment: please update your `anything` so we know exactly the problem